# simple loadtesting my nodejs app using loadtest module

Tags: node.js

I am trying to load test my nodejs app using loadtest module.My app accepts a json from a form and parse it.The form looks like

```
<form action="http://localhost:8081/json" 
  method="post" >
<label>
    Copy paste json
</label>
    <textarea name="json" required cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" ,id="submit">
```

Problem: When i try to loadtest this using the argument as below

```
loadtest.js -c 10 --rps 200 -P '{"json":"{"employees":[{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]}"}' -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -m POST http://localhost:8081/json
```

i am getting

```
req.body.json
```

as

```
undefined
```

A sample json that i expect is

```
{"employees":[
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
{"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
{"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}]}
```

I have googled and tried the documentations but i just cant get it fixed.
Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: do you check setting body-parser ?

Comment: It is working perfectly from request from browser. The problem is i cannot loadtest it using the module 'loadtest'

Comment: maybe error body url code  this  format  : MyVariableOne=ValueOne&MyVariableTwo=ValueTwo

Comment: How do you suggest me to change it? @trquoccuong

Comment: you can try "json=demo"

Comment: I have tried it but no result is coming

Comment: sorry  I forget & end of the string "json=demo&"